# Simulate Camera2 for unit testing

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm working on an image processing application and I'd like to set up some automated testing. So far, I've just been checking if the processed image "looks right" which is inefficient. I've set up an abstraction later that looks like this:

```
public interface ImageProcessor<T> {
    public T process(Image image);
}
```

which I can feed `Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();` into. This will work fine to test accuracy because I can feed images into it one by one and see if they are correct. However, I can't do much performance testing since I can't feed the frames into the processor at the framerate and format (YUV_420_888) of the camera. One option is to use a video, but the video will also have a capped framerate and won't be representative of the real thing.

Is there any way to simulate the camera by passing it a video, and expecting the frames of the video to come out as if they would come out of the camera?